# Some doubts on implementing custom error pages in Web2Py

Tags: python, web2py

I'm trying to implement a decorator for custom error pages in web2py
as per one of the haiti Todos. Ref -
http://web2py.com/AlterEgo/default/show/75

I'm trying to keep it as a module in /modules directory so that I can
import it into the controllers and place the decorator appropriately.

I have kept error handling decorator as
/modules/onerror.py

and am importing it like this from a controller say (or.py)-

```
exec('from applications.%s.modules.onerror import onerror as onerror'
                                                       % request.application)
```

HTTP object wasn't available in onerror.py so i did a -

```
from gluon.http import *
```

But then I readlized that the request object is also not available to
the decorator as in the line -

```
filename=os.path.join(request.folder,'views/errors/error%i.html'%status)
```

I have some doubts -

1. Is /modules directory a good place to keep such a reusable component?
2. Are the modules in the /modules directory automatically loaded as a
   new web2py instance is created? If so how can I access them in a
   controller?
3. Is there a way I can pass the request object to this decorator from
   my controller? Hints are welcome.

My current onerror.py - http://paste.pocoo.org/show/186165/
The way I'm trying to use in a controller - [http://paste.pocoo.org/show/186167/](http://paste.pocoo.org/show/186165/)

Let me know if I'm doing it in an unobvious way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Solved](http://groups.google.com/group/web2py/browse_thread/thread/93ec919b91ca0a84/58d77827d577c1fc#58d77827d577c1fc) through the web2py users mailing list.

> you can also use:  onerror = load_import('onerror').onerror
>
> > HTTP object wasn't available in onerror.py so i did a - 
> >     from gluon.http import *
>
> python modules are normal python modules in web2py as well. They only see
>   python keywords unless you import them. web2py has 5 special objects 
>   (request, response, session, cache, T) and your app has others (db, 
>   auth, crud). Because they are instantiated at every request, they 
>   cannot import by the module, they have to be passed explicitly to the 
>   functions in the module. Mind that while this is awkward this is what 
>   other frameworks ask to do all the time for all functions. web2py 
>   saves you this for models and controllers.
>
> > But then I realized that the request object is also not available to 
> >     the decorator as in the line - 
> >     filename=os.path.join(request.folder,'views/errors/error 
> >     %i.html'%status) 
> >     I have some doubts - 
> >     1. Are the modules in the /modules directory automatically loaded as a 
> >     new web2py instance is created? If so how can I access them?
>
> No. They are normal python modules. You have to import them to use 
>   them.
>
> > 2. Is there a way I can pass the request object to this decorator from 
> >        my controller? Hints are welcome.
>
> You need a meta decorator  def meta_decoration(something): 
>        def actual_decorator(f,something=something): 
>              do_whatever_you_want() 
>              return f() 
>        return decorator  @meta_decorator(request)  def function_to_be_decorated(): return dict()  Anyway you do not need this
>   decorator. Look into routes.examples.py  for routes_onerror. There is
>   a simple way to do what you want.